# Time limit Exceeded, i'm trying to remove duplicates in string using java stack using linked lists

Tags: java, stack

I am trying to write java stack using linked list code for removing duplicate elements in a string. Basically i am pushing elements in stack if they are not same as element in top otherwise i pop the top element. The remaining string is the required string.
'''

```
class Node{
char data;
Node next;
Node(char d){
this.data = d;
this.next = null;
}
Node(){
this.next = null;
}

}

class Solution {    
    public static Node top = new Node();

public String removeDuplicates(String S) {

    if(S.length() == 1){
            return S;
        }
    top = new Node(S.charAt(0));

    for(int i=1; i<S.length(); i++){
        Node newnode1 = new Node(S.charAt(i));
        if(top == null){
            top = newnode1;
            continue;
        }
        if(newnode1.data != top.data){
            newnode1.next = top;
            top = newnode1;

        }    
        else{
            top = top.next;
        }

    }
    String ans = "";
    while(top!= null){
        ans += top.data;
    }
    return ans;

}
}
```

'''

Comment: Is the input string sorted in an alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are iterating over the same top Node only, missed refreshing the top pointer

In your removeDuplicate(), before return statement, in the WHILE loop, try the mentioned change..

```
    while(top!= null){
        ans += top.data;
        top = top.next; // add this
    }
```

Comment: @EshuManohare Welcome! Kindly ACCEPT the answer, if it was precise. Thanks!